# Unable to use the FileEditorInput class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse Editor Project where I am supposed to get the location of the currently open file in the Editor. I searched the Eclipse documentation to actually find FileEditorInput Class. But to much of my surprise, my project is not able to locate this class in Eclipse. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileEditorInput` is `org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput`, however this is only used when you are opening an editor. When looking at the input of an existing editor use the `IFileEditorInput` interface (`org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput`).

The input to an editor is actually defined as `IEditorInput` which `IFileEditorInput` extends. If the editor is editing a file in the workspace it will normally be using `IFileEditorInput`. Editors can also have inputs of `IPathEditorInput` and `IURIEditorInput`.

Comment: The question is how do you find it. On my editor it says `org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: @Mishax You need to have `org.eclipse.ui.ide` in your plugin's dependencies, but you normally do not need to use `FileEditorInput`.

Comment: @greg-449 I found this question after having the same problem as the OP when following instructions from https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F. If one should not normally need to use FileEditorInput, how would one achieve the same goal (opening an editor with a given file) without using the FileEditorInput class?

Comment: @M_M You can use one of the `IDE.openEditor` methods where you specify the `IFile` to edit,